# ASP.NET display ListView InsertITemtemplate on button click

Tags: asp.net, listview

I want to display the ListView InsertITemtemplate on button click (i.e. not to be displayed by default) but couldn't manage to do it. I have tried `InsertItemPosition.None` but then it does not display on button click as well. I am sure it must be a very simple thing but I am running out of time for this task. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Ali

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
    <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1" InsertItemPosition="None">
    <LayoutTemplate>
      <div runat="server" id="lstProducts">
        <asp:Button ID="btnAddProduct" runat="server" Text="Add Product" 
              CommandName="Create" OnClick="btnAddProduct_Click" />
        <div runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
      </div>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
            <div><%# Eval("ProductName") %></div>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtProductName" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
    </InsertItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Then in code behind onclick event

```
    protected void btnAddProduct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListView1.InsertItemPosition = InsertItemPosition.FirstItem;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I handle this scenario client-side, with something like the following:

```
<InsertItemTemplate>
  <tr id="InsertRow" style="display:none">
    ...
  </tr>
</InsertItemTemplate>
```

Then you can set up a button (either a conventional html button or a Button control) with some client-side script such as:

```
<input 
    type="button" 
    value="Show Insert" 
    onclick="document.getElementById('InsertRow').style.display='';" />
```

to cause the row to display when you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

Add [CommandName="Insert"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemcommand.aspx) to your ASP.NET button.